# repmgr for streaming replication - standby register

Tags: postgresql, sql, postgresql-replication

I'm testing repmgr tool and I'm a little bit confused. Everything's fine until `standby register` step.

What should I have configured on `standby` server? From docs I assumed that `standby` should't have the cluster, but it didn't configure a new one. When the `postgres` cluster exists `repmgr` have a problem with existing data. When I'll stop the cluster service and delete the data manually and run the migration from `repmgr` I have an error after starting the cluster:

```
postgres@ip-10-0-34-147:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main start
waiting for server to start....postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

It's running on `Ubuntu`, but maybe more applicable will be `Debian`. But I still have no idea how to make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked without any problems under `Debian 10 Buster` OS.

After:

- stopping `PostgreSQL` service on the `standby` server,
- removing `PostgreSQL` data from the `standby` server,
- running data migration job from `primary` to `standby` server,

the `PostreSQL` service has started with migrated data as a `standby` server.